# Middleware with except and only not working in Laravel Resource controller

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware, except

I have two types of users. And I want to restrict users based on the method. But couldn't get below code to work at all. Works for admins but I was redirected with users to login page.
In my resource controller i use this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('is_admin');
    $this->middleware('verified', ['only' => ['index', 'create', 'store']]);
} // Not working & redirects with any of the user type
```

But individually it work fine as below

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('is_admin');
    } // works correctly only for admin
```

or

```
public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('verified');
        } // works correctly for verified users
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should try: `$this->middleware('verified')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);`

Comment: Tried as per this but doesn't work.  
$this->middleware('is_admin');
$this->middleware('verified')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);